# How to fix error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near ','.?

Tags: sql-server

I'm writing the following query

```
Create Table Worker
(
    Worker_ID Int Not Null Primary Key Auto_Increment,
    First_Name Char(25),
    Last_Name Char(25),
    Salary Int(15),
    Joining_Date Datetime,
    Department Char(25)
)
```

and getting this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near ','

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server doesn't have an `auto_increment` statement - try this instead, using the `IDENTITY` clause on your `INT` column to have SQL Server automatically create new values when inserting:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Worker
(
    Worker_ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    First_Name VARCHAR(25),
    Last_Name VARCHAR(25),
    Salary INT,
    Joining_Date DATETIME,
    Department VARCHAR(25)
)
```

Also: I would **strongly** suggest you use `varchar` instead of `char` to avoid filling up all your columns to the defined length with spaces.....

And last of all: the type `INT` (for your column `Salary`) in SQL Server **never** has a precision or anything - an `INT` is an `INT` is an `INT`. Maybe you wanted to define a datatype of `DECIMAL(p,s)` instead?